# How to insert data from Android apps to excel?

Tags: android, excel

I have some problem to inserting data drom mobile apps into excel. How do i know if the code is wrong? And i also want to make sure that it wont overwrite the previous data if multiple entry is inserted.

```
Public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button scanBtn, ExelWrite;
public static TextView resultSC;
EditText SetTemp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Activity activity = this;

    scanBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnScn);
    resultSC = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SC_text);
    ExelWrite = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ExelWrite);
    SetTemp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SetTemp);

    scanBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick (View view){

            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ScanCodeActivity.class));
        }
    });

    ExelWrite.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    Cell cell =null;
    CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIGHT_BLUE.index);
```

''' Creating Excel Sheet

```
    //Now Creating Sheet
    Sheet sheet = null;
    sheet = wb.createSheet("Name of Sheet");

    //Now column and Row
    Row row = sheet.createRow(0);

    cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue("Staff Credential");
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

    cell = row.createCell(1);
    cell.setCellValue("Staff Temperature");
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

    sheet.setColumnWidth( 0,(10*400));
    sheet.setColumnWidth( 1,(10*200));
```

''' Is this the Correct Code? I want to insert multiple data into excel

```
    //insert data
    for( int i=1;i>0;i++){
        Row rows = sheet.createRow(i);

        cell=rows.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue(resultSC.getText().toString());
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

        cell=rows.createCell(1);
        cell.setCellValue(SetTemp.getText().toString());
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    }
    File file = new File (getExternalFilesDir (null), "Staff_Temperature.xls");
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
```